# How can i add check mark in the item list while i clicked a particular item?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public void onPopup(View view)
{
    final PopupMenu menu=new PopupMenu(this,view);
    menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu.getMenu());


    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
        {

            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            item.getTitle()+"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         //Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourSpotActivity.class);
         //startActivity(intent2);

           startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourSpotActivity.class));

            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
            menu.show();


}
```

In this code i want to include check condition code. While i am clicking the list item then it was shown as tick mark or something we define.
I designed menu with four items. if i choose one of that item then it will shown as selected. What can i do in xml and main activity.

Comment: can you describe what you need with more details probably a picture

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't how to add picture in this site. i am new to this.

Comment: @Raghunandan i was created menu item with check box. but i don't how to code to select that particular check box as selected.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelected%28boolean%29